# Which is the best and easiest Python GUI toolkit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I found some many Python GUI toolkits. 
The ones I like are:

1. wxPython
2. pyGTK
3. Tkinter
4. pyQt
5. pySide

Which one is the best and easiest to use? 
And by the way what is the difference in pyQt and pySide? They both seem to be alike :/.

Comment: Tkinter is probably the easiest. Not going to say it is the best though...

Comment: Tkinter doesn't seem to have a lot of widgets built in it :\.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for SO - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: You might want to take a look at [dabo](http://dabodev.com/), which is built on wxPython.

Comment: @ Gerrat: I actually am asking this because I want to learn GUI Programming in Python and looking for an easy and good toolkit.

@ Michael: I know right :/.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: when you say Tkinter widgets are ugly, are you aware of the themed widgets that have been part of Tkinter for quite a while now? So many people say Tkinter is ugly without realizing Tkinter has improved a lot lately.

Comment: [easyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) is built on Tkinter. Easier to make something quick with, but not as flexible as Tk, given that it makes a lot of assumptions in order to keep it simple

Comment: @BryanOakley I had just been searching for newer screenshots to back up my claim, and finding that its not as bad as I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "best" nor "easiest". All of the toolkits you mention have strengths and weaknesses. I've had significant experience with wxPython and Tkinter, and both are nice. I would say Tkinter is a little easier, wxPython is a little more full-featured.

When someone asks me this question I tell them just to pick one. Once you learn one -- any one -- you'll be in a better position to decide for yourself which one is better than the others.

I recommend Tkinter just because you probably already have it, but if you're not afraid of installing other GUI toolkits, pick any of them and start coding.